# Sorting on a text field in elasticsearch without using Fielddata

Tags: java, elasticsearch

while trying to sort text field in elasticsearch 7+ it throws error that explicitly fielddata must be set to true. But that comes with a heavy price of extra memory consumption. 
As a workaround I decided to use a normalizer that would store the text field as a keyword.Below is the normalizer and the elasticquery that is being used.

```
//field mapping: {
                    "filterable_text": {
                        "match": "S_*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "copy_to": "_text",
                            "fields": {
                                "normalize": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
                                },
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword"
                                }
                            },
                            "type": "text",
                            "fielddata": true
                        }
                    }
                }
  //normalizer: "normalizer": {
                    "my_normalizer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "char_filter": [],
                        "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
                    }
                }

//query: {
  "track_total_hits":false, 
  "query": {"wildcard": {"doc.S_gName.normalize": "Ami*"}},
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 2,
  "sort" : [{
  "doc.S_gName" : {
    "order" : "desc"
  }
}]
}
```

But still I am getting the same error.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your mappings is correct, and you indexed the same field with text type and keyword type. Then you have to sort on the keyword field

if I have a mapping like this

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "text",
             "fields": {
                 "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword"
                  }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Then the sort will be

```
"sort" : [{
    "name.keyword" : {
        "order" : "desc"
    }
}]
```

in your case, it'll be

```
"sort" : [{
    "doc.S_gName.normalize" : {
        "order" : "desc"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Though I had already made the changes but would consider this as an answer, thanks.